# Using Compizconfig keybindings to run command

Tags: 11.10, keyboard, command-line

I'm trying to fix my keyboard keys brightness up/down.

Using `acpi_listen` pressing brightness up/down I have the result:

```
video DD03 00000087 00000000
video DD03 00000086 00000000
```

Running `showkey`:

```
keycode 225 press
keycode 225 release
keycode 224 press
keycode 224 release
```

I have set on compizconfi

Comment: I assume your holding down the Function key while pressing another key on your keyboard correct?  Is your screen doing anything at all?  Flickering, etc...?  If not then we need to bind those key presses to run a command that increases or decreases your brightness level.  If however your screen Flickers or makes some sort of adjustment then X is recognizing your buttons and we can go about this another way.

Comment: @ScottStookey hi...you are right about fn key, when I press it appears a black box on top right corner, as it does for sound (sound works perfectly) but for brightness it doesn't...so I think the brightness keys are being identified but not working

Comment: @ScottStookey on terminal I know this command `setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=xx` but I have no idea on how to change de XX for real values when pressing the keys

Comment: Ok... Yes they are being recognized so key recognition isn't a problem.  Let's do this and see if we can make the screen adjust.  Were going to install an app that we can use to adjust the brightness level.  Type the following in a terminal window:  `sudo apt-get install xbacklight`  After you have it install type the following at the command prompt:  `xbacklight -dec 50%` and see if the brightness decreases.  If it does type `xbacklight -inc 100%` to adjust to full brightness.  Report back on your findings.

Comment: Nothing happens and also no errors.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I had a backlight problem installing Ubuntu and so I had to change the `/etc/default/grub` file, the line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi = Linux"` don't know if it will mean something..

Comment: How is overall compiz working?  Are you able to use features in Compiz like wobbly windows, and Desktop Cube etc.?

Comment: My notebook is not so good with video, I'm using Unity 2D but I'm gonna test it and report back the results

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using 11.10? what kernel version?  `uname -r`

Comment: Works perfectly...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2612/discussion-between-scott-stookey-and-gerep)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to adjust the screen backlight of a monitor, laptop or integrated panel (such as the iMac) using software, but depending on hardware and model, sometimes only some options are available.

***Examples:***

- brightness is controlled by vendor specified hotkey. And there is no
  interface for OS to adjust brightness.
- brightness is controlled by OS:
- brightness could be controlled by ACPI
- brightness could be controlled by graphic driver.

There is an excellent article on Wiki summarizing the possible ways of doing this at:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Backlight

However if `ACPI`, `xbacklight` or `xcalib` fail to adjust your brightness levels we can use the `setpci` command to manipulate the graphics card directly.  This is the method we will be using for this tutorial.

**Note:** This method should only be used if the above mentioned programs fail to accomplish what your wanting to do and is not the preferred method for doing so.  However in numerous cases, its the only one that will.

---

**What were going to do is bind the `setpci` command to a key combination on your keyboard using `xbindkeys,` so that when certain keys are pressed your brightness will adjust up or down.**

**Ok Let's get Started!!**

- First we need to determine the ***Device Address*** of your graphics
  card, in most cases its going to be `00:02.0` but not always so
  here's how to check.

Open up a terminal window and at the command prompt type the following:

`lspci |grep -i vga`

This will return a line displaying information such as vendor, model, version etc...  The part were interested in is at the very beginning and should look something like the following:

`00:02.0`

**Note:** *Output may vary*

This is the ***Device Address*** of your graphics card and we will be using this along with the `setpci` command to control your brightness levels. **So Write It Down!**

---

- Next we need to download `xbindkeys`.  This will be the program that
  does the actual binding of the `setpci` command to the key
  combination on your keyboard.

Open a terminal window and type the following at the command prompt:

`sudo apt-get install xbindkeys`

- Now we are going to create two files in our ***Home*** directory that
  `xbindkeys` will use when it starts up.

Open a terminal window if you haven't already and change into your ***Home*** directory.  Type the following commands at the command prompt:

`touch .xbindkeysrc`

This creates a file that we will be typing our configurations into and it is read by `xbindkeys` each time it is started

`touch .xbindkeys.noauto`

This just creates a blank file but it is crucial because when it exists it keeps `xbindkeys` from starting automatically at boot.  Though we want `xbindkeys` to start automatically we want to control it ourselves because the Xserver starts it to early in the boot process.  This causes our configurations that we make to sometimes not function properly.  We will add a script called `xb_start.sh` to our ***Startup Applications*** later in this tutorial that will take care of the startup process.

---

***Let's find out what keys do what!!***

For time saving purposes I'm going to automatically assume that the *Xserver* already recognizes the keys you press on your keyboard to change brightness, it just doesn't do anything when you press them.  In my case its the `Fn` + `Up Arrow` or `Down Arrow`

But we can't just put the words `Fn`,`Up Arrow` or `Down Arrow` in our config file, we have to find out what the ***keycodes*** are.

In most cases they are going to be ***keycode 232*** to adjust the brightness down and ***keycode 233*** to adjust the brightness up but we better make sure.

Open a terminal window and type the following at the command prompt:

`xmodmap -pke |grep -i xf86monbrightness`

This should return two lines that look similar to the following:

`keycode 232 = XF86MonBrightnessDown NoSymbol XF86MonBrightnessDown`

`keycode 233 = XF86MonBrightnessUp NoSymbol XF86MonBrightnessUp`

The info were concerned about are the numbers that come after *keycode*.  In this case it's `232` and `233`.  **Write whatever numbers it is down for we will be using them later.**

---

***Let's start putting it all together!!***

- Now we're going to use the information that we've gathered and
  written down to add some lines to the `.xbindkeysrc` file you created
  earlier in your ***Home*** directory.

Using your favorite text editor, open the `.xbindkeysrc` file and either copy and paste or type the following lines to it and **save it**:

**Note:** *If `232` and `233` aren't the same keycodes you wrote down earlier, change them in this file*

```
"/usr/local/bin/blevel_down.sh"
c:232
"/usr/local/bin/blevel_up.sh"
c:233
```

What were doing here is telling `xbindkeys` to run the `blevel_down.sh` script when we press the key combo on our keyboard that adjusts brightness down.  In my case it's `Fn + Down Arrow`.  On the next line we're telling it to run the `blevel_up.sh` for `Fn + Up Arrow`

**Note:**  *Key combos vary, check the pictures on the keys of your keyboard to determine which ones they are for you.*

---

***Lets write the scripts!!***

The `blevel_up.sh` and `blevel_down.sh` scripts are created to incrementally adjust the brightness up or down by passing arguments to the `setpci` command.  So pretty much when you press whatever keys that do the adjusting, the brightness goes up a little or down a little each time.  The `xb_start.sh` is used to start `xbindkeys` when the computer boots up but allows for other processes to complete before doing so.

**Note:** If your Device Address of your Graphics card that we determined earlier differs from the one in `blevel_up.sh` and `blevel_down.sh` you will need to modify accordingly.  Most likely they should be the same.

- **We will create `blevel_up.sh` first:**

Open up your favorite text editor and either copy and paste or type the following into a file and **save it as blevel_up.sh in your Home directory**

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -f /home/$USER/.blevel ]; then 

    touch /home/$USER/.blevel
    echo "FF" > /home/$USER/.blevel
    state="FF" 

else

    state=`cat /home/$USER/.blevel`

fi

new_state=$(echo "$[0x$state+0x10]")

if [ "$new_state" -gt 255 ]; then 

    sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=FF

else

    state=$(echo "obase=16; $new_state" | bc)
    sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=$state
    echo $state > /home/$USER/.blevel

fi
```

---

- **Now we will create the `blevel_down.sh` script:**

Open up your favorite text editor and either copy and paste or type the following into a file and **save it as blevel_down.sh in your Home directory**

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -f /home/$USER/.blevel ]; then 

    touch /home/$USER/.blevel
    echo "FF" > /home/$USER/.blevel
    state="FF" 

else

    state=`cat /home/$USER/.blevel` 

fi

new_state=$(echo "$[0x$state-0x10]")

if [ "$new_state" -lt 15 ]; then 

    sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=0F

else

    state=$(echo "obase=16; $new_state" | bc)
    sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=$state
    echo $state > /home/$USER/.blevel

fi
```

---

- ***Now we will create the `xb_start.sh` script:***

Open up your favorite text editor and either copy and paste or type the following into a file and **save it as xb_start.sh in your Home directory**

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 10
/usr/bin/xbindkeys &
```

---

***Lets make the scripts Global!!***

- Now what we wanna do is move the three scripts we just created from
  our ***Home*** directory to `/usr/local/bin` and set the permissions
  so that no matter who is logged in on the machine they can execute
  them.

Open up a terminal window and type the following at the command prompt:

`sudo mv blevel_up.sh blevel_down.sh xb_start.sh /usr/local/bin`

`sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/blevel_up.sh`

`sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/blevel_down.sh`

`sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/xb_start.sh`

---

***Now to make `setpci` be able to run without typing a password each time***

Being that `setpci` makes changes to certain system files, a regular user would have to prefix `setpci` with `sudo` eachtime in order to run the command.  This would require you to enter a password eachtime you want to adjust the brightness of your screen.  If we make a particular entry in the `/etc/sudoers` file we can get around this.

Open a terminal window and type the following at the command prompt:

`sudo visudo`

This will open up the `/etc/sudoers` file so that we can make the required changes.

Scroll all the way to the bottom of the file and type the following:

`ALL    ALL = NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/setpci`

**Note:** *File is Case-Sensitive so type exactly how it is here*

**Save the file and exit**

---

***Almost Finished!!***

Last thing we need to do is add our `xb_start.sh` script to our Startup Applications so that `xbindkeys` starts at boot exactly when we want it to.

**Reboot and Enjoy!**

Comment: 100%!!! The only problem is that the box on the top right corner is gone but it worked perfectly...thanks Scott

Comment: That also solved the problem when my computer hibernates or when I close the lid...in those situations I had to restart to get full brightness..now its solved...amazing

Comment: The box on the top right doesn't show up anymore because xbindkeys is trapping the key combos before the Xserver does, causing it to run our scripts rather than whatever it was before that wasn't working.